# How to pass id with api call with react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

I have a react native app. And I try to pass the id with a api call. For the backend I am using django framework
If I do it hardcoded then it works. But if I pass the id then I get this error:

```
There was a problem with the fetch operation:, [Error: Network response was not ok]
```

So this is my service call:

```
export const fetchSubCategoryData = async (id) => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(`http://192.168.1.68:8000/api/categories/${id}/`, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
        });
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
        }

        return await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("There was a problem with the fetch operation:", error);
        throw error;
    }
};
```

But if I do this:

```
const response = await fetch(`http://192.168.1.68:8000/api/categories/${2}/`
```

Then it works

And this is the component that triggers the api call:

```
export const SubCategoryScreen = ({ route }) => {
    const [subCatgoryList, setSubCategoryList] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchSubCategoryData(route.category).then((data) => {
            setSubCategoryList(data);
        });
    }, [route.category]);

    return (
        <SafeArea>
            <CategoryList
                data={subCatgoryList}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                    return (
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log(item)}>
                            <Spacer position="bottom" size="large">
                                <SubCategoryInfoCard category={item} />
                            </Spacer>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    );
                }}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            />
        </SafeArea>
    );
};
```

So and this component you will navigate to SubCategoryScreen:

```
export const CategoryScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { loading, error, categoryList } = useContext(CategoryContext);
    return (
        <SafeArea>
            {loading && (
                <LoadingContainer>
                    <ActivityIndicator animating={true} color={MD2Colors.green200} />
                </LoadingContainer>
            )}
            <Search />
            <CategoryList
                data={categoryList}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                    console.log(item.id);
                    return (
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("groepen", { subcategories: item.id })}>
                            <Spacer position="bottom" size="large">
                                <CategoryInfoCard category={item} />
                            </Spacer>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    );
                }}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            />
        </SafeArea>
    );
};
```

the api call from the backend looks:

```
http://192.168.1.68:8000/api/categories/2/
```

Question: How to pass the id as parameter within the url?

subcategories is an array of objects:

```
Object {
  "animals": Array [],
  "category": null,
  "description": "vogels",
  "eaza": "",
  "id": 2,
  "images": "http://192.168.1.68:8000/media/photos/categories/birds.png",
  "legislation": "",
  "name": "vogels",
  "review": "",
  "subcategories": Array [
    Object {
      "description": "roofvogels",
      "id": 3,
      "images": "http://192.168.1.68:8000/media/photos/categories/predator_ETI4KPC.jpg",
      "name": "roofvogels",
    },
    Object {
      "description": "parkieten",
      "id": 5,
      "images": "http://192.168.1.68:8000/media/photos/categories/01-smartest-birds-NationalGeographic_2467639.webp",
      "name": "parkieten",
    },
    Object {
      "description": "",
      "id": 12,
      "images": "http://192.168.1.68:8000/media/media/photos/categories/seagull.png",
      "name": "meeuwen",
    },
  ],
}
```

So I try it like:

```
export const SubCategoryScreen = ({ route }) => {
    const [subCatgoryList, setSubCategoryList] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchSubCategoryData(route.params.subcategories).then((data) => {
            setLoading(false);
            console.log(data);
            setSubCategoryList(data);
        });
    }, [route]);

    return (
        <SafeArea>
            {isLoading && (
                <LoadingContainer>
                    <ActivityIndicator animating={true} color={MD2Colors.green200} />
                </LoadingContainer>
            )}
            <CategoryList
                data={subCatgoryList}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                    return (
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log(item)}>
                            <Spacer position="bottom" size="large">
                                <SubCategoryInfoCard subcategories={item} />
                            </Spacer>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    );
                }}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            />
        </SafeArea>
    );
};
```

Then I still get this error:

```
Invariant Violation: TaskQueue: Error with task : Tried to get frame for out of range index NaN
```

Comment: If you console.log(route.category) in your useEffect, what do you get? I believe that it should be route.params.category

Comment: @SlothOverlord. Hi, thank you. You mean like this:  useEffect(() => {
  fetchSubCategoryData(route.params.category).then((data) => {
   console.log(route.category);
   setSubCategoryList(data);
  });
 }, [route]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by passing the `subcategories` property of `data` instead of the whole `data` object  :

```js
setSubCategoryList(data.subcategories);
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be one issue with your code.

First, passed the subcategories param to the SubCategoryRoute on navigation

```
//You are passing {subcategories: item.id}
onPress={() => navigation.navigate("groepen", { subcategories: item.id })}>
```

And then you need to select that specific param when you are sending it to the fetchData function

```
     console.log(route.params) //See all params
    //You passed subcategories to this screen, this is where your ID is.
     fetchSubCategoryData(route.params.subcategories).then((data) => {
            setSubCategoryList(data);
        });
```

Comment: @SlothOverlord.Oke, I changed that. But then I get this error:  Invariant Violation: Tried to get frame for out of range index NaN

Comment: It could be an issue with the returning data. What type of data is being returned by your api? an object or array? You can console.log(data) above      setSubCategoryList(data) and see what you get

Comment: @SlothOverlord.array of objects

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong. But basically, somewhere in your code, it is expecting to receive an array, but it is getting an object instead. You should triple check the parts of your code where you are rendering a list. It's best to console.log the data before you are trying to render it to catch it.

Comment: @@SlothOverlordI get the correct data back. But the rendering of the flatlist is not going well yet.

Comment: @mightycodeNewton I'm not sure if I can help you any further since the code looks to be written ok. Try to search on stack overflow for the same error and see what their solution was.